# Ubuntu 16.04 - dark tabs in terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

I'm trying to make the tabs in gnome-terminal 3.18.3 dark. I have installing gnome-terminal.css from here:

https://gist.github.com/budnik/4184485

While this kind of works, as mentioned in the third comment on that page, the colors of the buttons change when loses focus.

What needs to be set to make sure the focused and lost-focused colors remain the same (i.e. so the button colors do not change when terminal loses focus)?